# DOM XML string replace bug

Tags: php, xml, string, domdocument

Can anybody explain this weird situation in PHP? Here is example.

I have string: **"Olbrachtova 10"**. I want to add comma before number and remove space before comma. So result will be.

**"Olbrachtova, 10"**

This string needs to be written in XML and I am using DOMDocument library.

I am using this code:

Function to find position of first number (works well):

```
private function findOffset($text){
        preg_match('/^\D*(?=\d)/', $text, $m);
        return isset($m[0]) ? strlen($m[0]) : false;
}
```

Funtion to insert character into string (works well too)

```
private function stringInsert($str,$insertstr,$pos)
{
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos) . $insertstr . substr($str, $pos);
    return $str;
}
```

And here is final script

```
//string to change
$address = "Olbrachtova 10";

//position of first number
$numberPosition = $this->findOffset($address);

if ($numberPosition){

    //remove space before number if exists
    if($address[$numberPosition - 1] == ' '){

        //remove space - HERE IS PROBLEM
        $address[$numberPosition - 1] = '';

        //find new position of number
        $numberPosition = $this->findOffset($address);
    }

    //add comma before number
    $address = $this->stringInsert($address,", ",$numberPosition);

}else{
   //if string has no number return false - is invalid
   return false;
}
```

After this processing I am trying to append final string which is "Olbrachtova, 10" to XML.

```
var_dump($address);

//return

string(15) "Olbrachtova, 10"
```

And here is final line to append

```
$parcel->appendChild($xml->createElement("Indirizzo", $address));
```

Output of this is:

```
<Indirizzo>Olbrachtova</Indirizzo>
```

It always break before comma, in the place where i removed space with

```
$address[$numberPosition - 1] = '';
```

**WHY?**

But when i am using this to remove space

```
$address = substr_replace($address,'',$numberPosition - 1,1);
```

Everything works great. Can anybody explain why the first method didn't work?

**EDIT**

Here is full code

```
    <?php


function findOffset($text){
        preg_match('/^\D*(?=\d)/', $text, $m);
        return isset($m[0]) ? strlen($m[0]) : false;
}

function stringInsert($str,$insertstr,$pos)
{
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos) . $insertstr . substr($str, $pos);
    return $str;
}


$xml = $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->formatOutput = true;

//main element for soap request
$mainSection = $xml->createElement("Info");

$parcel = $xml->createElement("Parcel");



//string to change
$address = "Olbrachtova 10";

//position of first number
$numberPosition = findOffset($address);

if ($numberPosition){

    //remove space before number if exists
    if($address[$numberPosition - 1] == ' '){

        //remove space - HERE IS PROBLEM
        $address[$numberPosition - 1] = '';

        //find new position of number
        $numberPosition = findOffset($address);
    }

    //add comma before number
    $address = stringInsert($address,", ",$numberPosition);

}else{
   //if string has no number return false - is invalid
   return false;
}

$parcel->appendChild($xml->createElement("Indirizzo", $address));

var_dump($address);


//append Package
$mainSection->appendChild($parcel);

//append whole xml to main
$xml->appendChild($mainSection);

$output = $xml->saveXML();

print_r($output);

?>
```

And you can test it here: http://phptester.net/

Comment: Please add the full source code of your PHP script. Also you might want to use `var_dump()` to output the variable values during the execution of your PHP script to see how the values are changed.

Comment: post edited, you can try it.. I think that it is bug in DOMDocument library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the empty string `""` to a string index. This results in the NULL byte being written at that location. From the PHP manual about [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

> **Warning**
>   Writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces. Non-integer types are converted to integer. Illegal offset type emits **E_NOTICE**. Negative offset emits **E_NOTICE** in write but reads empty string. Only the first character of an assigned string is used. Assigning empty string assigns NULL byte.

And the NULL byte marks the end of a string in C/C++ internally. So thats why the `createElement` method only writes the value "Olbrachtova" in the XML element, regardless of what the string looks like in php.

Solution: Do not write `$string[$index] = "";` under any circumstances

Answer (score 0):

Break the example down to the DOM functions with static strings. Try to reproduce. Maybe you have an error before that. Additionally do not use the second argument of `DOMDocument::createElement()` - it is not part of the DOM standard. Here is a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39521) that can break the XML. It should not be triggered by the example you provided, but it is safer to create the text node and append it.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document
  ->appendChild($document->createElement("Indirizzo"))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode("Olbrachtova, 10"));

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Indirizzo>Olbrachtova, 10</Indirizzo>
```